# Matlab: displaying 2D projections with specific color encoding as rgb images in 3D plot

Tags: image, matlab, graphics, 3d, 2d

As I could not find a solution by myself and related topics , I would like to to ask if someone can give me some hints how to resolve the following issue:

In a 3D plot it is possible to display 2D projections as (filled) contour plots by assigning the result of the function contourf to a graphics handle, as in the following matlab code fragment:

```
[~,h2]=contourf(w1,w3,sz,level_list2,'LineWidth',1);

h2=findobj(h2,'type','patch');

for j=1:length(h2),

     zd=w5(1).*ones(size(get(h2(j),'XData')));

     set(h2(j),'ZData',zd);

end

set(h2,'FaceLighting','none');
```

The arguments `w1` and `w3` of the function `contourf` define the x- and y-axis of the 3D plot, while `sz` contains the projection of the three-dimensional data set onto the (x,y)-plane.

However, as I want to use a specific color encoding for the 2D projection, a (filled) contour plot doesn't seem to be the appropriate solution.
Rather, the 2D projection is given as a RGB image after applying the procedure for the desired color encoding.

Therefore I tried to use the function `mapshow`, which seems to be more appropriate in this case. Then the corresponding code fragment reads

```
[~,h2]=mapshow(w1,w3,szIndexedImage,hsv);

h2=findobj(h2,'type','patch');

for j=1:length(h2),

    zd=w5(1).*ones(size(get(h2(j),'XData')));

    set(h2(j),'ZData',zd);

end

set(h2,'FaceLighting','none');
```

where the indexed image szIndexedImage is obtained from the rgb image szRGBimage via

```
szIndexedImage=rgb2ind(szRGBimage,hsv);
```

and `hsv` is the HSV color map.

Running the program leads to the error message

```
Error in `mapshow` (line 214)
error(nargchk(1,Inf,nargin,'struct'))

Output argument "varargout" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/toolbox/map/map/mapshow.m>mapshow".
```

Thanks a lot for any ideas which could help me to resolve this issue.

Best regards,

Joachim

Comment: Now the error dooesn't appear anymore. Thank you! However, the 2D projections are still not shown in the 3D plot. Additional assignments of the handles for the 2D cuts (such as h2 in the example above) to the 3D coordinate system might be required. Possibly my current code for the 3D representation ha=gca; 
set(gca,...
  'XLim',sort([w1(1),w1(end)]),...
  'YLim',sort([w3(1),w3(end)]),...
  'ZLim',sort([w5(1),w5(end)]));
daspect([100 100 4]);
view(3); 
camproj(projection_type); interferes with displaying the 2D projections. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling mapshow with output argument "[~,h2]", but mapshow only returns one output (the handle).  So while with contourf this means "don't return contour matrix, do return handle", with mapshow it doesn't make sense.

Just replacing [~,h2] with h2 should remove the error you're currently getting.